# How to set terminal tab titles font size?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I constantly get to a situation where my 1-2 character tab titles are cut, as I have over 20 tabs open. 
One way to solve my problem, would be to decrease the font size of the tab titles. Any idea how can this be done?

---

Thanks desgua, indeed I do decrease the system font to a certain degree (Application Font=9), but that's help to a certain degree only. I guess the best solution would have been to find a way to get rid of the tabs' close buttons, but haven't been able to find a way to do that.

Comment: I think, if you have no setting on that, you can make a new programme from a source, then compile it.

Comment: No can do… all modern DEs suffer from what dubbed "Havoc Pennington disease": we should be grateful for all the (little) configurability we got.  Those devs by and large bought into HPD, which means they like to believe there one setting for all.  (Havoc Pennington is on record saying he wants as little configurability as possible, and he doesn't even want an "Advanced" tab in settings)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to menu > System > Preferences > Appearance and change the font size of "Application font".

Comment: For Unity, you need to open Dash and type `Appearance` to open `System Appearance` application

Comment: @desgua: I assume these settings are system wide. I can only find `System Settings` > `Appearance`, where I can apparently not change this. I can't find a way in the Terminals own settings. Perhaps smth changed since your answer in 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks desgua, indeed I do decrease the system font to a certain degree (Application Font=9), but that's help to a certain degree only. I guess the best solution would have been to find a way to get rid of the tabs' close buttons, but haven't been able to find a way to do that.